# Fill Comboboxes by comboboxes

Tags: vb.net, combobox

i have 2 comboxes.,..,cbocourse and cboyearandsection

if i click BSIT on cbocurse then cboyearandsection will be automatically fill in without clicking any button except the selection of the index of cbocourse

```
 Dim BSIT() As String = {"1A", "1B", "1C", "2A", "2B", "2C", "3A", _
           "3B", "3C", "4A", "4B"}

 If cbocourse.SelectedIndex = "BSIS" Then
      cboyear.Items.AddRange(BSIT)
```

Comment: whats the actual question today?

Comment: In order to get an answer, you must ask a question.  Additionally, for specific help, you need to show us the code that you've attempted to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module level:

```
    Dim BSIT() As String = {"1A", "1B", "1C", "2A", "2B", "2C", "3A", _
       "3B", "3C", "4A", "4B"}
```

Assuming `cboCourse` contains strings like "ABC", "DEF", "BSIT", then:

```
 Private Sub cboCourse_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cboCourse.SelectedIndex

    If cboCourse.SelectedItem.ToString = "BSIS" Then
        ' dont want to add 2ce
        cboyear.Items.Clear()
        cboyear.Items.AddRange(BSIT)
    End If

End Sub
```

Caveats:

We dont know what is in `cboCourse`, it looks like strings.  If it is an object or index to something else, that would have to be resolved.  After you read up on events and cbo Selected... properties, work out how to start accepting some of the answers you get.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `If cbocourse.SelectedIndex` refers to the INDEX of the selected item, which will be an `Integer` value.  You can think of the items in your combobox as being in array.

If you want to compare to the `String` value of the selected item, you need

```
If cbocourse.SelectedItem.toString()
```

Comment: sir if selcted an item in cbocourse then cboyear will be filled.,.,how???like javascript.,.,it will be automatically field after it chooses an item

Comment: You should probably look into the `SelectedIndexChanged` method for ComboBoxes.  Within that method, put your logic for checking the selected item then filling the other combobox.

Comment: how can i flash this.,.,if cbocourse=BSIT then cboyear.Items.AddRange(BSIT).,.,.